# Looping a different number of times (determined by value in data) for each line

Tags: spss

I have to create a loop, but the size of this loop have to change according the  cell value. But I don't know how to reference a specific cell.
Example - my dataset has 2 rows:

```
Id    value  
1     10  
2     20
```

For the first row I have to run this loop 10 times, but for the second row I have to run 20 times.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
loop # = 1 to 1000. /*use the maximum number or runs necessary.
   do if # <= value.
       some transformations.
   end if.
end loop.
```

This will run the transformations on all cases every time, but will stop when the number of required runs for each line is reached.